# Warning: AndroidManifest.xml already defines versionCode

Tags: android

Can anybody explain this error to me?:

```
Warning: AndroidManifest.xml already defines versionCode (in http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android); using existing value in manifest.
Warning: AndroidManifest.xml already defines versionName (in http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android); using existing value in manifest.
Warning: AndroidManifest.xml already defines minSdkVersion (in http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android); using existing value in manifest.
Warning: AndroidManifest.xml already defines targetSdkVersion (in http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android); using existing value in manifest.
```

I'm building from within a full Android source base, and there's an Android.mk file being used for the build.

The resulting apk seems healthy enough, but I don't like unexplained warning messages in my builds.

I've searched up and down my source tree and those four variables are defined nowhere but in my AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: I think it means that (for example) the versionName value defined in the AndroidManifest.xml file is picked up in preference to any environment variable (e.g., "version.name") passed in via the ant command.

Comment: Hmmm; let me look into that.

Comment: @EdwardFalk Post your `AndroidManifest.xml` and your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 2):

in Android Studio these variables are defined in build.gradle file

```
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'org.example.'
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0 Beta"
}
```